# Auto fit CSS attribute to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on web application.

I wanted to apply auto height to textarea using CSS, dont want to use any script, jquery plugin and other stuff.

After applying class ( i.e. style property ) to textarea, it should automatically increase it's height not width as per content present it in.

In this case width should be fixed i.e. width: 98%; (In my case) only height needs to grow. So scroll bars should exist for text area.

I simply needed one CSS so that after applying to textarea, it should be auto grow like `<DIV>`.

Please folks do sugggest, is this possible using CSS. If this is not possible, then m okey if i get javascript statments to acheives my requirement.

Thanks,

Pravin

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible with straight CSS.

Comment: So you don't want to use javascript or jquery, but that's what you tag your question with? And you DO want to use CSS, but you don't use the CSS tag? Consider my mind blown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's sort of semi-doable in html/CSS. There are, however, the usual caveats of browser support and, since it uses html5's `contenteditable`, it requires a fairly modern browser.

That said, the following works (in Chrome/Ubuntu 10.04):

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="editThis" contenteditable>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
div#editThis {
    min-height: 4em;
    height: auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div#editThis:hover,
div#editThis:focus {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Demo posted at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/unote3/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing this....bt it seems that it's related to <DIV> , How do i supply this to <TEXTAREA> ?

Comment: It does apply to `div`, a `textarea` *already* has editable content. The problem, though, is that `textarea` won't use `height: auto` in the way that you want. So I used a `div` to force that behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only displaying text in a textarea and not using it to get more content input from the user then consider using a div and styling it to look like a textarea.

the other thing i have seen is an auto expanding textarea that grown in height as you type.

see here: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with pure CSS, you will need to use JavaScript

Comment: Thanks , i had dought for the same, I am okey if i get some javascript statments which achives my requirements.